# Getting results with a column value prioritized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, solr

```
Rails 3.2.8
```

I have the following:

```
def index
  params[:direction] ||= "desc"
  params[:sort] ||= "status"
  @products = product.solr_search( include: [:customer] ){
    fulltext params[:query] if params[:query].present?
    with :status, (params[:status] || params[:filter]) if (params[:status] || params[:filter]).present?
    order_by( params[:sort], params[:direction] ) if params[:sort].present? && params[:direction].present?
    paginate page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page]
  }.results
end
```

What I would like to do is do the initial sort with a priority when the status column = 'new'. In MySQL, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT * from product ORDER BY case when status = 'new'
```

Any idea what my syntax should be?